# How to read all objects from ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, file

I have a file with some info how can I read all info?

```
Name names;    
try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            names = (Name) objectInputStream.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) to know how to ask a question.

Comment: If you are referring to serialization, I believe one stream can be one object.  It can be a composite of multiple object (e.g. ArrayList), but a single object nevertheless.

Comment: I tried add objects into HashSet but had an exception java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC. I input name using scanner and than I need to check if name already exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several solution, all depending on the input:

- You can iterate until the stream is fully consumed: I think that is the worse solution out of those I provide you. It is worse because you are checking if EOF was reached, whilst you should know when you're done (eg: your file format is wrong).

  ```
  Set<Name> result = new HashSet<>();
  try { 
    for (;;) { 
      result.add((Name)objectInputStream.readObject());
    }
  } catch (EOFException e) {
    // End of stream
  } 
  return result;
  ```
- When producing the input, serialize a collection and invoke `readObject()` on it. `Serialization` should be able to read the collection, as long as each object implements `Serializable`.

  ```
  static void write(Path path, Set<Name> names) throws IOException {
    try (OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(path);
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os)) {
      oos.writeObject(names);    
    }       
  } 

  static Set<Name> read(Path path) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(path);
         ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is)) {
      // WARN Files.newInputStream is not buffered; ObjectInputStream might
      // be buffered (I don't remember).
      return (Set<Name>) ois.readObject();
    }
  }
  ```
- When producing the input, you can add a `int` indicating the number of object to read, and iterate over it: this is useful in case where you don't really care of the collection (`HashSet`). The resulting file will be smaller (because you won't have the `HashSet` metadata).

  ```
  int result = objectInputStream.readInt();
  Name[] names = new Name[result]; // do some check on result!
  for (int i = 0; i < result; ++i) {
    names[i] = (Name) objectInputStream.readObject();
  }
  ```

Also, `Set` are good, but since they remove duplicate using `hashCode()`/`equals()` you may get less object if your definition of `equals`/`hashCode` changed after the fact (example: your `Name` was case sensitive and now it is not, eg: `new Name("AA").equals(new Name("aa"))`).

Comment: I tried your code and I got an java.io.EOFException

Comment: That's good, this means that you reached the end of the file, there are no more object to read. Handle this exception properly, like printing a message saying "All the objects read" or something...

Comment: And instead of array I can use HashSet? and print it to console?

Comment: I fixed my example. Beside, converting an array to a collection should not be a problem if you are tackling serialization.