# Deserialize many objects in same file (java)

Tags: java

When serializing objects, I set,

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path +"\\"+filename,true);
```

to append objects to serializing file. As an example, I serialize **Email** objects into the same file.

when deserializing these saved objects, I wanted to get all objects, but It gives only the very first object.

```
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
Email sentEmail = (Email) objectInputStream.readObject();
```

I found a similar question about this,
[Deserialize many objects in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928510/deserialize-many-objects-in-java) but there is no, `objectInputStream.hasNext()` method. So, how to get all objects when deserializing?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923911/reading-serialized-objects-from-a-binary-file-in-java/33924112#33924112) answer your question?

Comment: Just keep reading objects until you catch `EOFException`, then stop.

Comment: But note that you can't append to a file with `ObjectOutputStream` without taking special measures. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607969/appending-objects-to-a-serialization-file?noredirect=1&lq=1) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Serialize a Collection of Email objects. You should be able to read the collection with all Email Objects. For further information read [How to read all objects from ObjectInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53467133/how-to-read-all-objects-from-objectinputstream) on SO.